# Accordion open page and expand when clicking parent

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an accordion menu with which I am trying to accomplish the following:

When clicking on a parent, a submenu appears AND opens a site I am specifying.
Upon clicking a submenu-item, this page loads and sublist stays expanded

I have accomplished the latter, however I am unsure how to go about to make the accordion parent node open a new site.

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="accordion" id="menu"">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a data-parent="#menu" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = ""})">&nbsp;Home
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#ServiceSublist" >&nbsp;Services
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="ServiceSublist" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service 1", "Service1", "Services", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service 2", "Service2", "Services", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu ul li').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
            $('#menu ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

        }
    });

    $('a').filter(function () {
        return this.href === document.location.href;
    }).addClass('active')

    $(function () {
        var arr = window.location.pathname.split("/");
        $(arr).each(function () {

            if (this == "Services") {
                $('#ServiceSublist').collapse('show');
            }


        })

    });
});
```

The problem lies here (I believe)

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#ServiceSublist" >&nbsp;Services</a>
```

as the href points to #ServiceSublist which it needs to. How can I also make that line open a new window? I have tried using onclick="", however this really messed up the menu and added the entity TO the menu (which I do not want.. I just want to open the page and keep sublist expanded).

**Note:** The source here is a modified version of what I am using, but the general idea is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a id to your anchor tag-

< a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" id="service" > Services

Then on click of that opening a new window

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $('#service').click(function () {
            window.open("https://www.google.co.in/");
        });
```

});

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, my fault for not specifying in question that I wanted to open the link in the same window. I ended up going with anchoring and then; $('#Services').click(function () {
     location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Services", new { area = ""})'
    });